# Convert numeric date string (dd/mm/yyyy) to newline-separated string with short month name

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function setTableHeader(v,k) {
            for (var i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
                $('.data-date-set').append('<th>' + result1[i] + '</th>');
            }
        }
```

I got function called **setTableHeader** which gets **(v,k)** .

**v** receives dates such as **(Dynamic dates)**

```
"30/03/2020"
"31/03/2020"
"01/04/2020"
"02/04/2020"
```

It is appended to

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="Tablev">
        <tr class="data-date-set">
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

and then it draws a grid view which has those dates as columns.
ouput-

```
30/03/2020|31/03/2020|01/04/2020
          |          |
```

But i need the Output like this-

```
  30    |   31   |   01
  Mar   |   Mar  |  Apr
 2020   |  2020  |  2020
        |        |
```

So, in order to achieve this is there any easy way of doing this rather than using a switch.

Comment: You can use ```moment```. Just do ```moment(date).format('DD MMM YYYY')```

Comment: You can use string split with /, and the use an array of month names as a lookup for the month.

Comment: moment is easy ... your own array to lookup months is better ... but [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) is how real programmers do it :p

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [`Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) to convert your date into suitable format and apply [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace default delimiter with required (`\n`,`<br\>`, etc):

```js
const dates = ['30/03/2020','31/03/2020','01/04/2020','02/04/2020'],
      formatDate = s => 
        new Date(s.split('/').reverse())
          .toLocaleDateString('en-GB',{day:'numeric', month:'short',year:'numeric'})
          .replace(/ /g, "<br\>")
          
$('#Tablev tr').html(
  dates.map(dateStr => `<th>${formatDate(dateStr)}</th>`)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="Tablev">
  <tr class="data-date-set"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `Date.toLocaleDateString()` to get the month name based on the month number.

```
var event = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20));

var options = { month: 'short'};

var month =event.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
```